# How to interpolate vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, complex-numbers, wave, interpolation

I've got these known variables:

```
T=3;             
t=0:0.01:5*T;    
om=2*pi/T;       
N=10;            
f0=100;
```

where:

- `T` = period,
- `t` = variable time,
- `om` = angular frequency,
- `N` = number of terms of the series,
- `f0` = starting force (power)

And I am creating vector `ft` using complex Fourier series like this:

```
ft=zeros(size(t));
for j=1:2*N+1
    n= j-(N+1);    
    if n==0
        f(j)=f0/2;
    else
        f(j)=f0*((exp(-i*n*2*pi)*(i*2*pi*n+1)-1)/(4*pi^2*n^2));   
    end
    ft=ft+f(j)*exp(i*n*om*t);
end
plot(t,ft);
```

Result is the following sawtooth wave:

[image: sawtooth wave]

Okay, vector `ft` is complex and my question is: **How to interpolate vector `ft`?**

Comment: And I thought the linear interpolation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). If `t2` is a vector containing the interpolation times, then:

```
ft2 = interp1(t, ft, t2);
```

returns the interpolated points in `ft2`.

Comment: Stupid question, I don't get it - the vector interpolation times t2? Sorry :(